# GoogleCloudStorage blob.download_to_filename(path) not working indocker google.auth.exceptions.TransportError host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

`GoogleCloudStorage blob.download_to_filename(path)` works outside docker but within docker i am getting this error

```
2023-08-17 10:36:51,265 - WARNING - Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa7c87c5cf0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname')': /token
2023-08-17 10:36:51,269 - WARNING - Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa7c87c59c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname')': /token
2023-08-17 10:36:51,274 - WARNING - Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa7c87c5810>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname')': /token
2023-08-17 10:36:51,281 - ERROR - Error processing image: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa7c87c4e50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname'))


google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f19dcfb0850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname'))
```

I want the upload and download functionality to work - Google cloud storage